# Implementing Python integer key and value numpy dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a large amount of data which I need to lookup quickly and usually I would use a dictionary. However, I need to store around 600million key-value pairs and when trying to store this in a dictionary it didn't fit in memory.

I realised that a dictionary could save on memory if it stored the key and values as integers with a fixed length (i.e. 32bit). I can solve my problem by using numpy arrays, sorting the data and then using a search to find the right values (takes up around 8GB):

```
import numpy as np    
key_a = np.zeros(600e6, dtype=np.int64)
values_a = np.zeros(600e6, dtype=np.int32)

# ... Fill arrays ...

# Find value using key:
index = np.searchsorted(key_a, key_to_find)    
value_to_find = values_a[index]
```

This approach isn't as fast as using a hash.

What I would ideally like to do is implement a dictionary but using fixed size numpy arrays as the backbone to save on space? I also want the dictionary to be optimised for intergers. Why doesn't numpy already offer something like this and how would I go about doing this?

Comment: As far as I know, numpy arrays are not meant to be used as databases, i.e. fast indexing. Maybe pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) might help you out...

Comment: Have you considered using an on-disk structure like a `dbm`? It obviously won't be as fast or as compact as a custom int32 hash, but it would be a lot simpler (as in, just one `import` statement instead of 100 lines of code you have to write and debug), and it also gives you persistent (which I'm guessing you're going to want) for free.

Comment: Speed is crucial, so a in-memory solution is preferable

Comment: I should have asked this earlier, but… do you frequently look up a bunch of keys that are close to each other? If so, a hash will have a serious cost over a sorted array, because you'll lose all cache and VM locality. And, depending on your data distribution, there are ways you could speed up that binary search that might help.

Comment: @abarnert Yes the keys are only in a certain range. How can you speed up binary search?

Comment: @Josh: For example, if the distribution is relatively dense and flat, jumping X% of the way between `lo` and `hi` (where `X` is the % of the way between `a[lo]` and `a[hi]` that the key is) approaches constant instead of logarithmic. For a multiset, if the distribution is very overdense, changing it into an array of unique values and counts instead of an array of duplicate values can speed things up. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would ideally like to do is implement a dictionary but using fixed size numpy arrays as the backbone to save on space

A fixed-size array is obviously going to give you a fixed-size dictionary. (You obviously can't do chaining, because you can't stick a linked list in a numpy array of ints…) Is that acceptable?

> I also want the dictionary to be optimised for intergers.

What exactly would this mean? You still need to hash the integers in order to get a decent distribution of the keys. Maybe you can come up with a slightly faster hash function for fixed-size integers, but I doubt it's going to give you much performance benefit.

> Why dosn't numpy already offer something like this

Because it's not very closely related to what numpy is all about, numerical programming. In fact, even things which *are* somewhat related to numpy but aren't "fundamental" enough tend to get shunted into libraries like scipy rather than in numpy itself.

> how would I go about doing this?

Do you not know how to implement a hash table? A StackOverflow answer is not the place to learn the basics of an elementary data structure, but [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)'s looks pretty good.

If you want it to work as closely like Python's `dict`'s hash table as possible, the best thing to do is to look at the source. [CPython](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b2e9d845bc6c/Objects/dictobject.c) actually does a great job explaining how it works in the comments. But of course it's C code, not Python, so unless you understand some basic C and get what it's doing, it's not going to make sense to you. You may want to look at PyPy instead—although its source is a bit more complicated (it has a number of optimizations that CPython doesn't), it is in Python.

There are also a number of [custom hash table implementations on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=hash+table&submit=search).

You can also check out [`fixedhash`](https://github.com/abarnert/fixedhash). I wrote it to be as simple a hash table as possible as a foundation to show the impact of different probing functions (the one that it starts with is simple linear probing), but I guess it should also work as a foundation to show how to build as simple a hash table as possible. :) It's built around a `bytearray` to store 8-byte `bytes` keys and values; changing it to use an `np.ndarray` to store 4-byte integer keys and values should be obvious, and the fact that you can use an Nx3 or Nx4 array should make it more readable (none of that `struct.pack` stuff).

Comment: This answer has given me a lot of direction, thanks.